# MySQL - Count instances from another table in last twelve months based on date column

Tags: mysql, date

- I have a customers table with a status (either active or cancelled) and a notes table with all customer interactions (calls)
- If a customer has cancelled, the cancellation date is listed in the customers table
- I want to count the number of notes on a customer in the last twelve months (LTM), where the LTM should either be the current LTM if the customer is still active, or the LTM before cancellation date

Does anyone have some pointers for me? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yep. Here's a pointer: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Treat active customers as cancelled as of today.

Answer (score 0):

select count(whichever_unique_column) from table_name where date_column_name < DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL -12 MONTH);

something like this.

or am I missing something about where the issue is?

Comment: Well, you're missing at least a part of the criteria.

Comment: i trust OP is capable of adding that, since the title of the question is asking about the count and "last twelve months", so I assume his issue is with either (or both) of those two...? i mean, i'm being charitable. otherwise, this whole question just looks like "plz give me teh codez"

Comment: It does, doesn't it.